# Ruby on Rails redirect_to arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is always a degree of black magic when it comes to Rails and I can't find the documentation to help me figure out this one. What redirect_to does is clearly straight forward. In fact, this question isn't even directly related to, but an argument I see passed to redirect_to often and can't understand where that argument is coming from. For instance, if you scaffold a new object, let's say 'user', you'll see some code like this in user_controller.rb:

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

Question is, what exactly is users_url here? Where does it come from? Can someone point me in the right direction in as far as documentation goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users_url` in this case is the full URL path to the view users. This is autogenerated by Rails action_dispatch based on your domain object. If you are interested on the documentation on this, you can read it [from here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#urls-and-paths).

HTH

Answer (score 3):

There are many named routes that Rails automatically generates if you use resource based routes. You can see those by running `rake routes`. Other examples would be `edit_user, user`and`new_user`. By appending `_url` to that name, the name will be resolved to the matching url. And the url is what redirect_to needs.

Comment: Some useful reading material on this can be found at RailsGuides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: That last statement isn't true. `redirect_to` will happily take a path. Use the `*_url` form if you need the full URL rather than a relative path.